# Doing Apply(str) to int creates a bunch of \n's?

Tags: string, dataframe, integer, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe like this labeled by year:

[image]

I would like to change these `ints` to `strs` because they are actually categorical variables. However, this is the result:

```
X_train['YrSold'] = X_train['YrSold'].apply(str)
```

[image]

I would prefer to get rid of all those `\n`'s automatically in the `.apply(str)` process, as opposed to postprocessing each column via regex. Seems like the latter would have more room for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was `astype(str)` instead of `apply(str)`